# Converting Oracle Procedure into MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, data-conversion

I'm trying to convert this procedure from Oracle to Microsoft SQL. I used SQLINE without success. The code is supposed to insert up to rows into the table. It is working fine in Oracle and just want to do something similar in MSSQL.

Here is the Proc

````
 ```create or replace procedure insert_emp as 
    begin
for p in 0..1000 loop
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||1,'Bob',30000,'02-FEB-2004','SALES','EMP');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||2,'Raj',80000,'02-MAR-2018','MRKTNG','EMP');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||3,'Kevin',90000,'05-APR-2010','ADMIN','EMP');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||4,'Laila',30000,'12-FEB-2004','PURCHASE','EMP');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||5,'Steve',100000,'15-JAN-2008','SALES','MGR');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||6,'Lucy',80000,'10-FEB-2014','MRKTNG','MGR');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||7,'Nathan',120000,'17-JUN-2012','ADMIN','MGR');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||8,'Jose',60000,'16-JUL-2015','DESIGN','EMP');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||9,'Andrew',80000,'18-AUG-2005','SALES','EMP');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(p||10,'Lata',90000,'02-FEB-1998','SALES','EMP');
end loop;
commit;
end ;```
````

And here is the converted proc in SQLINE but it does not run in MSSQL.

````
   ```begin
declare p cursor for 0..1000 open p;
 fetch p into;
 while @@fetch_status=0
 begin   
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+1,'bob',30000,'02-feb-2004','sales','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+2,'raj',80000,'02-mar-2018','mrktng','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+3,'kevin',90000,'05-apr-2010','admin','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+4,'laila',30000,'12-feb-2004','purchase','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+5,'steve',100000,'15-jan-2008','sales','mgr');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+6,'lucy',80000,'10-feb-2014','mrktng','mgr');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+7,'nathan',120000,'17-jun-2012','admin','mgr');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+8,'jose',60000,'16-jul-2015','design','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+9,'andrew',80000,'18-aug-2005','sales','emp');
if p<>0 begin  
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(isnull(p, '')+0,'lata',90000,'02-feb-1998','sales','emp');
end 
fetch p into;
end;
close p;
deallocate p;
commit;
end;```
````

Thanks!

Comment: Why have you tagged [[tag:mysql]] as well here? Why do you want to use a `CURSOR` here, which are well known to perform terrible (in T-SQL). Why are you doing 9 separate `INSERT`s instead of 1 `INSERT` with 9 rows (which is far more performant)? Rather than asking us to translate the code, explain what it does, so that someone else can explain how to achieve it. Finally, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Also, please [edit] your question to explain what exactly `it does not run` means in your case. Are you getting errors? Wrong results?

Comment: tagging mysql was a mistake. I'm trying to insert random data into the table, that's all.

Comment: @PM77-1 It does not in MSSQL. The conversion tool I use is transforming the code with a CURSOR.  Here are some error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '0.'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 29
Incorrect syntax near ';'.

Comment: `DECLARE @p INT = 0; WHILE @p < 1000 BEGIN ...; SET @p += 1; END`. Cursors are not appropriate here, and the tool appears quite clueless about how to write T-SQL in general, so I'd ignore it and read the docs yourself instead. You'll want a `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at the start and a `COMMIT` at the end, as otherwise each individual insert needs to wait on the transaction log, which is hideously slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @P INT = 0;
WHILE @P < 100
begin   
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+1,'bob',30000,'02-feb-2004','sales','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+2,'raj',80000,'02-mar-2018','mrktng','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+3,'kevin',90000,'05-apr-2010','admin','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+4,'laila',30000,'12-feb-2004','purchase','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+5,'steve',100000,'15-jan-2008','sales','mgr');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+6,'lucy',80000,'10-feb-2014','mrktng','mgr');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+7,'nathan',120000,'17-jun-2012','admin','mgr');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+8,'jose',60000,'16-jul-2015','design','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+9,'andrew',80000,'18-aug-2005','sales','emp');
insert into emp (empno, empname, salary, hiredate, dept, title) values(@P+0,'lata',90000,'02-feb-1998','sales','emp');
SET @P+=1;
end ;
```

Comment: Oracle PL/SQL blocks are implicitly transactional, so the TSQL should include BEGIN TRAN/COMMIT outside the loop.